# Display json data using jquery in html page

Tags: jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.messboxcontent { display:none; background: rgba(0,0,0,.4); width: 400px; height: 100px; margin: 50px auto; padding: 15px;}
.mess_test {display: inline-block; cursor: pointer ; vertical-align: middle; width:165px; height:35px; background:blue; bottom:0px; left:144px; margin-right: 16px}
#msg_holder {overflow-x:scroll ;overflow-y: hidden; white-space: nowrap; position:fixed;height:110px; width:100%; background-color:yellow; bottom:0px;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
 done();
});
function done() {
      setTimeout( function() { 
      update();       
      done();
      }, 20000);
} 
function update() {
     $.getJSON("fetch.php", function(data) {   
       $.each(data.result, function(){    
        var message = this['message'];
        var name =  this['name'];
call(name, message);
 });
});
};
function call(name, message){
$("#msg_holder").append("<div class='mess_test'>"  + name +   "<div>");
$(".mess_test").click( function() {
          $('div.messboxcontent').html(' name :&nbsp;&nbsp; '+ name + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  Message &nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp; ' + message);
          $('div.messboxcontent').fadeIn();
   return false;
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="messboxcontent"></div>
<div id="msg_holder"></div>

</doby>
</html>
```

and this is the fetch.php file

```
{"result":[{"message":"this is jaja","name":"jaja"},{"message":"this is koka","name":"koka"}]}
```

when ever i click on a blue box that Contain any name, it always fade in the latest message and name. what i want is when i click on the box that contain jaja as a name i want the box that contain message: this is jaja,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use delegates for adding events to dynamic tags,

```
$("#msg_holder").append("<div class='mess_test' message='"+message+"'>"  + name +   "<div>");

    $(document).on("click",".mess_test", function() {
          $('div.messboxcontent').html(' name :&nbsp;&nbsp; '+ $(this).html() + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  Message &nbsp;&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp; ' + $(this).attr("message"));
          $('div.messboxcontent').fadeIn();
   return false;
});
```

Comment: it gives me the same thing , the second message.

Comment: its working fine for names, but the message is the same. how can i do the same for messages also .

Comment: of course i will accept as answer, thanks for your help. about your editing it give me message undefined , if you have any idea please help me.