# Display json data in html div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

**Html file:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .messboxcontent { display:none; background: rgba(0,0,0,.4); width: 400px; height: 100px; margin: 50px auto; padding: 15px;}
    #mess_test {display: inline-block; cursor: pointer ; vertical-align: middle; width:165px; height:35px; background:blue; bottom:0px; left:144px; margin-right: 16px}
    #msg_holder {overflow-x:scroll ;overflow-y: hidden; white-space: nowrap; position:fixed;height:110px; width:100%; background-color:yellow; bottom:0px;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        done();
    });
    function done() {
        setTimeout( function() { 
            update();       
            done();
        }, 2000);
    } 
    function update() {
        $.getJSON("fetch.php", function(data) {   
            $.each(data.result, function(){    
                var message = this['message'];
                var name =  this['name'];
                var age = this['age'];

                $("#msg_holder").append("<div id='mess_test'>"  + name +   "<div>");
                $(document).on("click","#mess_test",function(event) {         
                    $('div.messboxcontent').html(' name : ' + $(this).html() + ' Message : ' + $(this).html() + ' age ; ' + $(this).html() );
                    $('div.messboxcontent').fadeIn();
                    return false;
                });
            });
        });
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="messboxcontent"></div>
    <div id="msg_holder"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**fetch.php:**

```
{"result":[{"message":"message-7iii","name":"name-maja", "age":"33"},
{"message":"message_gggggg","name":"name-koka","age":"44"}]}
```

I was searching about how to retrieve notification from database for a weeks. I found this method.

A user receives all messages as a notification box with just the username of the sender.
He clicks on that notification box.

Another box with the name, age, and message fade in.

However, I can't pass those tree variables (name, age, message). For example, when I receive 2 messages two notification boxes appear, each one with a sender name. So when I click on the first notification box, which has kaka as the name, another box that contain the name: kaka, his age, and the message appear. When I click on the second notification box, I want that box to show up again with the name of the sender, his age, and the message.

Comment: Check out [this article](https://coderwall.com/p/1pcc_g) on how to "pretty print" JSON. It may help you.

Comment: This is the fourth time you have posted this question in 3 days and the second time TODAY.  I am marking this and all you other duplicate questions as such.  Of the five questions you asked, four of them mimic this one EXACTLY.  Learn to use Stackoverflow properly or don't use it at all.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Display json data using jquery in html page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644679/display-json-data-using-jquery-in-html-page)